# Normalizing a Python list to get JSON data into a Tables

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I am trying to use the following python code to draw info from an API and create a players table ultimately.  I have gotten the data mostly normalized to that level, but am struggling to work with the [rosters] list.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

r1 = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/16?hydrate=franchise(roster(season=20182019,person(name,stats(splits=[yearByYear]))))')
data = r1.json()

df1 = json_normalize(data, 'teams',['teams.franchise'],errors='ignore')['franchise']

df2 = json_normalize(df1)['roster.roster']

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2.index, columns=['Id'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2.values, columns=['Players'])

df4
```

returns:

```
0   [{'person': {'id': 8470645, 'fullName': 'Corey...
```

Any ideas on what I could do to extract each person from this API into a table?  IE:

```
ID | fullName |
..   .....
..   .....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the main problem is this is a deep dictionary. Some inspection showed that this code will get you to each player:

```
all_players = []
for team in data['teams']:
    for player in team['franchise']['roster']['roster']:
        player = player['person']
        print(player.keys())
        print(player)
        print()
```

However, some of the keys in `player` correspond to more dictionaries. So you'll either have to decide which player fields are basic values like strings/ints/etc and keep those, or add more code to parse out the additional dictionaries.

But this code will get you to each player, then you can normalize how you want from there.

Let me know if you need help!